# Can I list only tables and/or views, no indexes?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using `psql` on terminal and looking for all tables and views, but "`\d mySchema.`  and tab" shows all objects, not only the important ones.

Comment: `\dt` will do it

Comment: Thanks @MikeOrganek! With the `\dv` that I discover with your clues, we close this question. Delete it, or you want to answer?

Comment: Thank you, but I will not answer.  It's up to you whether to delete it since this is worded differently than other forms of this question on SO.

Comment: Should the title say "view" instead of "index"?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Well, seems not... The text of the question is about "important objects"... Imagine important for usual SELECT queries... But, ok, your comment make sense, to be more precise I changed the title to *"tables and/or views"*.

Answer (score 1):

On `psql v12.3` the `\?` command say:

```
  \dt[S+] [PATTERN]      list tables
  \dv[S+] [PATTERN]      list views
```

So, using "`\dt mySchema.` tab" you obtaim all TABLE names and with "`\dt mySchema.` tab" you obtaim all VIEW names.